# Converting snake_case to camelCase

Tags: sql-server

Please provide an approach to convert snake_case to camelCase in SQL

For example:

```
created_by
last_updated_by
item
item_id
```

The preceding fields should be converted as

```
createdBy
lastUpdatedBy
item
itemId
```

Comment: This is not an easy task for SQL, which is not good at string manipulation in general. it's even worse in SQL Server, that does not have proper regex support. You will need to kind of iterative or recursive process, which seems like over-complicated for a task that can easily be done on application side.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is not the best tool for this job.  But if you always use the best tool for every job, you'll end up with too many tools.

Here's a quick example in TSQL with some of the scaffolding left in:

```
create or alter function ToCamelCase(@in nvarchar(128))
returns nvarchar(128)
as

/*
highlight and run to test cases

  select dbo.ToCamelCase('last_updated_by')
  select dbo.ToCamelCase('LAST')
  select dbo.ToCamelCase(null)
  select dbo.ToCamelCase('_LAST_UPDATED_BY_')

*/
--uncomment single-line comments for dev and to debug
--declare @in nvarchar(128) = 'last_updated_by'
begin
  declare @i int = 1;
  declare @len int = len(@in);
  declare @rv nvarchar(128) = '';
  declare @nextUpper bit = 0;
  while @i <= @len 
  begin
    --print(@i)
    declare @c nchar(1);
    set @c = substring(@in,@i,1);
    --print(@c)

    if @c = '_'
    begin
      set @nextUpper = 1;
      set @i = @i + 1;
      continue;
    end
    else
    begin
      set @rv = @rv + case when @nextUpper = 1 then upper(@c) else lower(@c) end;
      set @i = @i + 1;
      set @nextUpper = 0;
      continue;
    end
  end

  --print(@rv)
  return @rv

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string splitter that is ordinal position aware, such as [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2), and split and rebuilt. This would likely be far faster than a iterative process:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.YourString,
           CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DS.Item ELSE STUFF(DS.Item,1,1,UPPER(LEFT(DS.Item,1))) END AS Camel,
           DS.ItemNumber
    FROM (VALUES('created_by'),
                ('last_updated_by'),
                ('item'),
                ('item_id'))V(YourString)
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.YourString,'_') DS)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Camel,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ItemNumber) AS CamelCase
FROM CTE
GROUP BY YourString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function;

```
CREATE function [dbo].[CamelCase](@Text as varchar(8000))returns varchar(8000)as
begin   
declare @Reset bit;   
declare @Ret varchar(8000);   
declare @i int;  
declare @c char(1);   
select @Reset = 1, @i=1, @Ret = '';      
while (@i <= len(@Text))    
select @c= substring(@Text,@i,1),               
@Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset=1 and @i > 1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c) end,               
@Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,               
@i = @i +1   
return replace(@Ret,'_','')
end
```